# Saxon is slow parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxon

I am trying to parse some xml with saxon to make some xpath querying on it but got 2 problems : the first one is that saxon is very long to build a very short document in xhtml.
code is this :

```
Processor processorInstance = new Processor(false);
    processorInstance.setConfigurationProperty(FeatureKeys.DTD_VALIDATION, false);


    XPathCompiler XPathCompilerInstance = processorInstance.newXPathCompiler();
    XPathCompilerInstance.setBackwardsCompatible(false);

    String expressionTitre = "//div[@class='score_global']/preceding-sibling::img[1]";

    XPathExecutable XPathExecutableInstance = XPathCompilerInstance.compile(expressionTitre);
    XPathSelector selector = XPathExecutableInstance.load();
    logger.info("Xpath compiled.");

    // Phase 2, load xml document.
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilderInstance = processorInstance.newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilderInstance.setSchemaValidator(null);
    documentBuilderInstance.setLineNumbering(false);
    documentBuilderInstance.setRetainPSVI(false);


    XdmNode context = documentBuilderInstance.build(new File("sample/sample.xml")); // This line takes ages to return.
```

What I don't understand is that if I do it with SAX, it loads at normal speed :(.
What did I forget to provide in saxon ?

Java 1.6
Saxon 9.1.0.8

Second problem is that he is unable to process accented characters while my xml was like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

So I removed xml:lang en lang= attributes but got no better luck :(

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well After much reading, it was simply necessary to define a CatalogResolver and downloading locally the Xhtml dtds. I dropped saxon and used simple JaxP/SaxReader instead.

This page http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html proved very interesting.

Hope this considerations will prove themselves useful to someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found out that although I configured Saxon not to validate, he nonetheless tried to resolve the URI and did not manage to find it locally, so he went online and gets & 503 from W3c which takes a long time to return.
I removed the DTD declaration in my xml, and it worked.
My next step is to make it stop to try to resolve it. I am currently reading saxon doc and playing with entity resolver and it should be ok.

Comment: Please combine this with your other "answer."  No reason to have two of them.  Thanks.